# Unable to run flask app on gunicorn wsgi server

Tags: flask, gunicorn, wsgi

I'm unable to run flask app using gunicorn. I'm getting a modulenotfound error.

> gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 wsgi:app
>       [2019-12-26 18:42:02 +0000] [6374] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
>       [2019-12-26 18:42:02 +0000] [6374] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (6374)
>       [2019-12-26 18:42:02 +0000] [6374] [INFO] Using worker: sync
>       [2019-12-26 18:42:02 +0000] [6378] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 6378
>       [2019-12-26 18:42:02 +0000] [6378] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 578, in spawn_worker
>           worker.init_process()
>         File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
>           self.load_wsgi()
>         File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 135, in load_wsgi
>           self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
>         File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
>           self.callable = self.load()
>         File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
>           return self.load_wsgiapp()
>         File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
>           return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
>         File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 377, in import_app
>           **import**(module)
>         File "/home/arunsharma/PycharmProjects/myproject/wsgi.py", line 1, in 
>           from myproject import app
>         File "/home/arunsharma/PycharmProjects/myproject/myproject.py", line 2, in 
>           import mammoth
>       ImportError: No module named mammoth
>       [2019-12-26 18:42:02 +0000] [6378] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 6378)
>       [2019-12-26 18:42:02 +0000] [6374] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
>       [2019-12-26 18:42:02 +0000] [6374] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.

This is my error, but when its run simply its have been execute without any error. I am also using gunicorn3 but error will be the same. could you help me please?. My main motive is I would like to run my app as production server.

Comment: It looks like you are using python2

Comment: yes, gunicorn3 didn't work too.

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Missing python module, Please run :

```
pip install mammoth
```

Comment: thanks, I have installed but its didn't work. I could simply run this code when I'll use gunicorn its raise an error